# Knockout.js Auto Save Form

Tags: knockout.js

I am brand new to knockout.js. I have an html form that I want to auto save so if the user leaves the form and comes back everything previously entered is still there.

If auto save is not possible then I still need to understand how to save a form.

Is there a good example or tutorial somewhere to get started with this?

Answer (score 0):

> ..... then I still need to understand how to save a form.

The fields in the html form is saved on server when user submit the form.Like:

```
<form action="place the server path where you want to send the form data" method="post">
     Username: <input type="text" name="user">
     <input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
```

In the above form when user will press submit button than all the input fields inside the form will send to server.You should mention the path where you want to send the data in **action** attribute of form tag.For more info [check this](http://www.w3schools.com/html/html_forms.asp).

> ......so if the user leaves the form and comes back everything previously entered is still there.

Here i am assuming that user leave the form without clicking on submit button. So in that case you can save the form data in browsers memory. For this purpose you can use:

1). [LocalStorage](http://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_webstorage.asp) [From Html5 web storage]

2). [Store api from amplifyjs](http://amplifyjs.com/api/store/) [Plugin]

Comment: Thank you for this info. I am still researching the best/easiest method for saving form data in my application. Knockout seems to be popular right now.

Answer (score 0):

The AutoSave is dependant on an isDirty Flag whose implementation in KnockoutJS autosaves the required Dirty Filed to the server and updates it as clean.
The entire implementation is kindly explained by rniemeyer at his site below.
It's being updated here as it was helpful to me in my project and so that anyone else reading this question knows where to go to get the full answer.

http://www.knockmeout.net/2011/05/creating-smart-dirty-flag-in-knockoutjs.html

Just in case, if the links go down, here's the essential code.

This is your HTML.

```
<style>
  li { padding: 2px; margin: 2px; }
  input { width: 75px; }
  .dirty { border: solid yellow 2px; }
</style>

<ul data-bind="foreach: items">
  <li data-bind="css: { dirty: dirtyFlag.isDirty }">
    <span data-bind="text: id"></span>
    <input data-bind="value: name" />
    <button data-bind="click: dirtyFlag.reset">Reset</button>
  </li>
</ul>
<button data-bind="enable: isDirty, click: save">Save</button>
<hr />
<h3>Just Dirty Items</h3>
<div data-bind="text: ko.toJSON(dirtyItems)"></div>
```

**This is your javascript**

```
<script src="http://knockoutjs.com/downloads/knockout-2.2.0.js"></script>
<script>
ko.oneTimeDirtyFlag = function (root) {
   var _initialized;

   //one-time dirty flag that gives up its dependencies on first change
   var result = ko.computed(function () {
       if (!_initialized) {
           //just for subscriptions
           ko.toJS(root);

           //next time return true and avoid ko.toJS
           _initialized = true;

           //on initialization this flag is not dirty
           return false;
       }

       //on subsequent changes, flag is now dirty
       return true;
   });

   return result;
};

ko.dirtyFlag = function(root, isInitiallyDirty) {
    var result = function() {},
        _initialState = ko.observable(ko.toJSON(root)),
        _isInitiallyDirty = ko.observable(isInitiallyDirty);

    result.isDirty = ko.computed(function() {
        return _isInitiallyDirty() || _initialState() !== ko.toJSON(root);
    });

    result.reset = function() {
        _initialState(ko.toJSON(root));
        _isInitiallyDirty(false);
    };

    return result;
};


function Item(id, name) {
    this.id = ko.observable(id);
    this.name = ko.observable(name);
    this.dirtyFlag = new ko.dirtyFlag(this);
}

var ViewModel = function(items) {
    this.items = ko.observableArray([
        new Item(1, "one"),
        new Item(2, "two"),
        new Item(3, "three")
    ]);

    this.save = function() {
        alert("Sending changes to server: " + ko.toJSON(this.dirtyItems));  
    };

    this.dirtyItems = ko.computed(function() {
        return ko.utils.arrayFilter(this.items(), function(item) {
            return item.dirtyFlag.isDirty();
        });
    }, this);

    this.isDirty = ko.computed(function() {
        return this.dirtyItems().length > 0;
    }, this);
};

ko.applyBindings(new ViewModel());

</script>
```

This is where it's come from.
http://jsfiddle.net/rniemeyer/dtpfv/